# How to open Custom URL like Apple TV "videos://" in WKWebView from a WebPage

Tags: ios, url, wkwebview

I have an app which consists entirely of a WKWebView that connects to a webpage. Inside my web page I want to have a button that opens the Apple TV App. This can be done in Safari on your iPhone by simply putting in "videos://" for the URL. It will either open the AppleTV app or prompt you to install it.

When I try the same thing from my App which is using the WKWebView, I get a : 

**"WKWebViewVC::didFailProvisionalNavigation Code : -1002 Description : unsupported URL"**

I am not trying to embed the AppleTV app inside the WKWebView, but rather have it open and go to the AppleTV app, same as if you put the "videos://" in safari.

I have searched StackOverflow and Google extensively and found information on using a custom scheme handler but that fails with an error. Even if the setURLSchemeHandler worked, I'm not sure what to put in the start method of the custom scheme handler.

```
webConfiguration.setURLSchemeHandler(CustomSchemeHandler(), forURLScheme: "videos://")
```

The Error I get from setURLSchemeHandler is :
**'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ''videos://' is not a valid URL scheme'**

If safari can handle this, I'm sure it can be done via the WKWebView.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. You need to use the WKNavigationDelegate for the WKWebView to handle the request for the "videos://" URL. Here is the method that checks to see if my request contains this URL and if so redirect it to the AppleTV app and do not open in the WKWebView, which cannot handle it.

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

    if let requestUrlString = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString {
        if (requestUrlString.contains("videos://")) {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(navigationAction.request.url!) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(navigationAction.request.url!)
                    decisionHandler(.cancel)
                    return
            }
        }
    }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```